# Не работает префикс -g в cmd, как быть?

Tags: node.js, npm

Привет! 
Столкнулся с такой проблемой
[image: Error -g]

```
C:\Users\Admin>npm install -g npm
"CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Кроме того при вызове, например, команды `npm -version`, то же самое сообщение.

---

Раньше все было норм, есть подозрения, что подобный сбой мог произойти после попытки установки программу wget (для скачивания сайтов), которую я пытался установить, но она не работала, поэтому я ковырялся в "Переменные среды/Path", потом не получилось, удалил.. вот.
   Сначала думал, что проблема именно здесь, поэтому переустановил 1 раз обычным способом, 2 раз дополнительно удалял папки npm из папки "Roaming", перезагружал комп, вобщем, вроде "сделал все что мог".

---

Доп. скрин:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я надеюсь, что проблема решится правильной настройкой переменных в свойствах системы. 
Не могли бы вы посмотреть содержание Path на вашем компе? Ну это я так.. мало ли.

PS: в какую директорию устанавливаются пакеты с ключом -g ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages